# Webserver wth phpMyAdmin running. How Do I Connect to the database I created?

Tags: mysql, database

I have my raspberry pi running a webserver publicly with a domain name. I also successfully installed phpMyadmin and created a database with the tables I need and also a server following a few tutorials. I am running a html5/js file on the index.html. How do I connect to my phpMyAdmin Database that is also installed on the Pi? I am not sure about what to put on the hostname. All I need to do is a get of the information on one of the tables. All I get is connection error. perhaps I have also tried on hostname to put 192.168.0.101/phpmyadmin.

```
 var mysql = require("mysql");
new mysql.createConnection({
     "hostname": "192.168.0.101", //this is the ip address of the ip not the ip of the computer
     "user": "pi", //user of DB
     "password": "pass", //pass for DB
     "database": "compraflanDB" 
}).connect(function(error) {
     if (error) {
         return console.log("CONNECTION error: " + error);
     }
     this.query()
         .select(["*"])
         .from("order")
         .execute(function(error, rows, columns){
             if (error) {
                 console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
                 return;
             }
             console.log("CHILLIN");
             // Do something with rows & columns
         });
});
```

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly are you trying to do? Use phpmyadmin to navigate and inspect tables? Or read table data into a web page? Phpmyadmin does not have databases. Phpmyadmin is a php script that allow you to view and inspect MySQL databases and included tables. When you install it, it creates a configuration file that tells Apache to serve (and hopefully execute via a handler) the phpmyadmin file when you navigate to //localhost/phpmyadmin. If you wish to retrieve data inside a web page, please rephrase, excluding phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

For hostname put localhost. The ipaddress would have worked but it doesn't want the name of a file or directory just the hostname (e.g. 192.168.0.101 not 192.168.0.101/phpmyadmin).

Comment: Well, as you can see I already tried that. Remember that on 192.168.0.101 all I have is a index.html file and a directory called phpMyAdmin with everything inside. All I want is to access my DB.

Comment: @Joseph If you are trying to access phpmyadmin do as C Resse suggests and open a browser on your pi and go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin. If the problem is with the script above then please post the specific error message.